# Edit key-value pairs in a file using Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

so I'm currently facing a problem when writing a new Ansible Playbook. My goal is to edit the key-value pairs in a file called example.conf, which is formatted like this:

```
name: John
age: 23
city: Los Angeles
```

This would be the whole file.
So let's say, I want to edit the values of the attributes and change the content of the file to:

```
name: Michael
age: 31
city: San Francisco
```

I'm new to Ansible (this is the first playbook I'm writing myself), that's why I'm not familiar with the different options for tasks.
I would only need help with the task itself, everything considering the usage of variables etc. can be done afterwards ;)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dict.html) module and loop over the line you want to edit, e.g.

```
  tasks: 
  - name: Replace value in file
    lineinfile:
      path: example.conf
      regexp: '^{{item.key}}:'
      line: "{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}"
    with_dict: {name: Michael, age: 31, city: San Francisco}
```